# Alerts/Errors with Twitter Bootstrap and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

folks.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to quickly build a small app with Ruby on Rails, and I seem to be having an issue with using the `bootstrap-sass` gem.

I added the requisite line to my Gemfile, and executed `bundle install`.  The problem is...it doesn't seem to be putting the bootstrap CSS file that's needed inside `vendor/assets/stylesheets` that should be there.

So when I have this login (using Devise), it's not showing proper style at all:

[image: Bootstrap Not Working!]

This ERb:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
          <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

is generating the following HTML, which seems to be correct, according to the Bootstrap documentation, which -should- be generating a Bootstrap styled red-colored "error" alert box:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
  <div id="flash_alert">Must be logged in to access the admin area.</div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what the problem is.  Related information is as follows:

- OS:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise) x86 -- Inside a Vagrant VM Ruby
- Version:  2.0.0-p247
- Rails Version:  4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `*= require bootstrap` at the top of your `application.css` file. Or as the `bootstrap-sass` [documentation](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) says, you can use `@import "bootstrap";` instead.

Comment: I've got a few lines in my application.css.scss already.  `*= require_tree .` is one of them, and I have a file called `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` in the assets/stylesheets folder that has a `@import "boostrap";` line in it.  Maybe I should just throw that import directly into the file, instead of doing it that way.

Comment: I don't know if `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` is included... Can you add a small CSS rule to this file to see if it works ?

Comment: I just moved `@import "bootstrap";` directly into the application.css.scss file, and it's still not working correctly.  No idea what is going on.  When I look at the displayed page's source, then investigate the CSS file, it seems like Bootstrap's CSS is indeed getting loaded properly.

Though when I search the CSS for the `alert-error` class, it's not there, though there's a bunch of other different `alert`-related classes in there.

Comment: OK so your file is being loaded into the document, that's good news! So, what exactly is working and not working on the page? I think `alert-error` is not part of Boostrap, use `alert-danger` for the red color instead.

Answer (score 5):

Romain, thanks for the help.  I made sure to "hardcode" the importing of bootstrap using your method, and also fixed a problem on my own.

The documentation I was using to name my alert class in ERb was old.  Apparently they changed the class for an alert 'error' in Bootstrap from `alert-error` to `alert-danger`.  I failed to realize that change from Bootstrap 2.x to 3.x, whoops.

Still, I'll mark your answer as accepted because it helped solve the issue.  Cheers!